# Unbounded function on bounded interval not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I can't figure out how to prove this statement.

If $I$ is a bounded interval and $f$ is an unbounded function defined on $I$, then $f$ cannot be uniformly continuous.

It seems pretty obvious to me that this statement is true, and I figure it has to do with the fact that $|x-x_0|$ is, at most, equal to $|b-a|$ if $I$ is defined to be $(a,b)$ while $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ could be infinite. Help?

Comment: $I$ presumably should be a bounded interval.  You can select $(x_n)$ with $|f(x_n)-f(x_{m})|>1$ whenever $n\ne m$. Now consider an accumulation point  of $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ cannot be infinite if $f$ is a real valued function. You just cannot bound it by a constant for all $x$ simultaneously.

Secondly you just can stick to the defitions. If $f$ where UC, then to, say, $\varepsilon = 1$ there would be $\delta > 0$ st $|x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < 1$. Now choose $n $ such that $n\delta > |b-a| $ (assuming $I=(a,b)$)

Using the triangle inequality you can then easily derive that for any $x,x_0$ in $(a, b)$, $|f(x) - f(x_0)|\le n\cdot 1 = n$ , so $f$ is bounded, contradicting the assumption.

Assume, e.g.,that $x< x_0$

The last inequality is then true since you can find $k$ points $\{x_i\}$ such that $k\le n$ and $x< x_1 <\ldots x_k < x_0$ such that the difference between $x, x_1$, between $x_k, x_0$ and between each pair $x_i, x_{i+1}$ is less than $\delta$, so
$$|f(x)-f(x_0)| = |f(x)-f(x_1) +f(x_1) -\ldots - f(x_k)+f(x_k) -f(x_0)|\le |f(x)-f(x_1)|+|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|+\ldots+|f(x_k)-f(x_0)|\le k $$

Comment: I understand up to the last point, but I don't understand how the triangle inequality applies here or how that chosen $n$ helps with $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$.

Comment: I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $I$ is a bounded set and $f(I)$ is unbounded. We shall show that $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Suppose to the contrary that $f$ is uniformly continuous. Since $f(I)$ is unbounded then  the sets$X_n= \{x\in I:|f(x_n)|\ge n\}$ are non-empty for all $n$, so there is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\in X_n$. Since  $(x_n) \subset I$ there is a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ (which converges to a point which is not necessarily at $I$ ). So $(x_{n_k})$  is Cauchy and then $(f(x_n{_k}))$ is also Cauchy (uniformly continuous function maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences) and hence is bounded, a contradiction.