# Uniformly Continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$, can f be extended to $[0,1]$ in such a way as to be right continuous at $0$ and left continuous at $1$ ? Justify your answer.

I was trying to give a counterexample such that $f(x) = x^3$ and take the limit from the left and right.

would someone help me out with this question .

Answer (score 3):

Let me help you in interpreting what the question is asking.  I think once you can understand fully what the question is asking, you will be able to come up with the solution on your own.

We know $f$ is a function with domain $(0,1)$, and $f$ is uniformly continuous on this domain.  So, if you were to draw the graph of the function on the $XY$-plane, you would only draw it over the interval $(0,1)$ on the $x$-axis.  It's also continuous, so you can never "pick up your pencil" when you are drawing it.

Now, this function takes values from $(0,1)$ to $\Bbb R$.  Every element of $(0,1)$ is sent to some real number in $\Bbb R$.

The question now is: what happens to the function as you approach $0$ from the right?  Does it approach a real number?  If not, then it must either approach $\infty$ or $-\infty$.  If it approaches a real number, then we can *extend* $f : (0,1) \to \Bbb R$ to a new function $\hat{f} : [0,1) \to \Bbb R$ by defining $\hat{f}(x) = f(x)$ if $x \in (0,1)$, and $\hat{f}(0) = $ the limit of $f(x)$ when we approach $0$.

Similarly, if the limit of the function as we approach $1$ from the left is also a real number, we could *extend* $f$ to $\hat{f} : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$, by just defining $\hat{f}$ as $f$ on $(0,1)$ and the limits on $x = 0$ and $x = 1$.

But this only works if the limits are real numbers.  But we could also have $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = \infty$ (or $-\infty$).  And similarly, we could have $\lim \limits_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x) = \infty$ (or $-\infty$), in which case we would *never* be able to extend $f$ to $[0,1]$ and keep it being continuous.

So the question for you is: in the case where one of the limits mentioned in the last paragraph is $\infty$ (or $-\infty$), can $f$ still be *uniformly* continuous?  It *could* be continuous, but can it be uniformly continuous?  If not, then that means uniform continuity on $(0,1)$ would imply the limits are finite as we approach $0$ and $1$, so that we **could** extend $f$.

So at the end of the day, you have to determine whether if we have a function $f(x)$ which satisfies $\lim \limits_{x\to 0^{+}} f(x) = \infty$, can this function also be *uniformly* continuous?

Comment: You have explained very well but I do not know what should I wright for an answer for that . Thank you

Comment: There is another possibility other than converging or diverging to $\pm\infty$. It can also simply not settle down, such as $\sin 1/x$ does at $0$.

Comment: there is anything to do with Lim Sup and Lim inf ?

Comment: @AhmadTalafha Here is what you need to do: Suppose $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = \infty$.  Prove that you can't have uniform continuity of $f$, i.e., the following statement is *not* true: For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ so that $|x - y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.  So you need to prove that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, $|x - y| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(y)| \geq \epsilon$.

Comment: By the way, I recommend using the formal definition of $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = \infty$, which is to say, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - 0| < \delta \implies f(x) > \epsilon$.

Comment: Suppose limx→0+f(x)=∞there is no  uniform continuity of f, i.e., the such that for every ϵ>0, there exists δ>0 so that |x−y|<δ⟹|f(x)−f(y)|<ϵ. So, there exists some ϵ>0 such that for all δ>0, |x−y|<δ and |f(x)−f(y)|≥ϵ|f(x)−f(y)|≥ϵ.ϵ>0, there is some δ>0such that |x−0|<δ⟹f(x)>ϵ. should I add anything to this ?

Comment: @AhmadTalafha The proof that you wrote down isn't correct.  In everything I've written here, I've just been explaining the problem to you and the ideas behind the problem.  And I also told you what you needed to show, but I haven't actually told you how to show it.  The proof you wrote in your latest comment is not the correct way to show it.

Comment: would you please wright out the proof to me. I kinda understand what is the point but I could not really follow up it. So please help me out. Thank you in advance

Comment: @AhmadTalafha You're essentially trying to prove that if $f$ is an unbounded function with domain a bounded interval, then $f$ cannot be uniformly continuous.  This is proved here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721420/unbounded-function-on-bounded-interval-not-uniformly-continuous